# save indexed images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, indexed-image

I have this image which with point curse it shows[image]

X ,Y
index
RGB

the index values are important for me and I want to save this image and use it later. but when I am using

```
imwrite(im, 'importantIm.png' , 'png')
```

the created image does not have index value. here is the resulting saved image (png format);
[image]

I produce im , like below

```
im=zeros([1204 1204]);
```

with a loop add data to it.

Comment: With indexed image you refer to the information which is displayed in the tooltip? It should be written to the file as well? How is it created, think you must save the figure, not the image.

Comment: no, I just wanted to show that the "index" is important for me. not graphically save the view in the figure. When I am writing this image in png format, its index converted to 0-255. but i want to save the original index.

Comment: So it is not about the index but about the data type conversion from 0...1 scaled double values to uint8? What about 3 color channels vs 1 color channel, is that irrelevant? Is your original image in the 0...1 range?

Comment: The value inside the index in my image, 38.61 is  added by loop  to the "im" and i want to have them in png file. but when I am oping my saved png , I have index is equal to 0 or 255. So I can say I do not want this conversion. I added the saved resulting image.

Comment: You can't save floating point data in an image unless it's normalized between `[0,1]`.  If you want to save the values exactly, I suggest you simply save the data as a MAT file to be recalled later.  Don't save them as images.